# 502 - Bad gateway - AspNetCore with Docker in Azure WebApp Container

Tags: .net, azure, docker

Please,

I customized docker image because my app (API with AspNet Core 3.1) use a COM DLL with dependencies.
I did make download and installed runtimes and in local env the container fine work.
But in Azure Web App, my app returned only 502 (bad gateway). I tried config WEBSITES_PORT to 5001, deleted UseHttpsRedirection... but doesn't work. What I can do?

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8

WORKDIR /app
# Visual C++ 2015 Multithreaded Runtime DLLs (vcruntime140.dll)
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN VC_redist.x64.exe /install /quiet /norestart /log vc_redist.log

ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/974313ac-3d89-4c51-a6e8-338d864cf907/6ed5d4933878cada1b194dd1084a7e12/dotnet-sdk-7.0.302-win-x64.exe dotnetsdk.exe
RUN dotnetsdk.exe /install /quiet /norestart /log dotnetsdk.log

ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/476eba79-f17f-49c8-a213-0f24a22cd026/37c02de81ff5b76ac57a5427462395f1/dotnet-runtime-3.1.32-win-x64.exe dotnetcoreappruntime.exe
RUN dotnetcoreappruntime.exe /install /quiet /norestart /log dotnetcoreappruntime.log

ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/98910750-2644-472c-ab2b-17f315ccb953/c2a4c223ee11e2eec7d13744e7a45547/aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.32-win-x64.exe aspnetcoreruntime.exe
RUN aspnetcoreruntime.exe /install /quiet /norestart /log aspnetcoreruntime.log

# Build Stage
WORKDIR /src
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out    
    
# Serve Stage
#WORKDIR /app
COPY /out c:/app/

WORKDIR /app
COPY "dependencies/zlib1.dll" c:/Windows/System32/
COPY "dependencies/libxml2.dll" c:/Windows/System32/
COPY "dependencies/libeay32.dll" c:/Windows/System32/

#WORKDIR /Windows/System32
RUN "C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe /i /s C:\app\dependencies\ReportDFe_Reg_x64.dll"

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://*:5000;https://*:5001"

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DanfeAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Netcore don't need .exe files. Are you deploying on Linux? Did you try locally on linux?

Comment: No, I deployed in Windows container because of the COM DLL.

Comment: I don't understand about it. I deployed image in Azure using ports 443 and 80 and worked for me. But, two days after, the 307 error back again.